# How to get access to form's controls from class C#

Tags: c#, winforms, infinite-loop

I've got problem when I am trying to get access to form's controls from another class. My program is hanging in infinite loop. I know why, but I don't know how to write this correctly.
Here is Form1.cs (to my Form)

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load config = new Load();

        string[] data = config.readConfig("config.ini");
        if (data.Length == 4) { //client
            Client run = new Client();
            run.startClient(data[1], Convert.ToInt32(data[2]));
        }
        else if (data.Length == 3) //server
        {
            Server run = new Server();
            run.startServer(Convert.ToInt32(data[1]));

        }
    }


public void addLog(string dataLog){
            richTextBox1.Text += dataLog;
        }
```

and here is Client.cs file:

```
class Client
{

    public void startClient(string ipAddr, int port)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            try
            {

                form1.addLog("Connecting...");

                client.Connect(ipAddr, port);
                form1.addLog("Connected to server: " + ipAddr + ":" + port.ToString());

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("We couldn't connect to server");
            }

    }


}
```

How can I change text value without running each time new form. Maybe There is something like run_once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite loop is here:

Form1:

```
//Always runs if the config file is a certain length
Client run = new Client();
```

Client:

```
 Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

Each constructor creates the other object, which in turn creates the first object, ad infintum.

If you need to get the form object to the client **don't create a new one!**. It doesn't work anyways, as your new form object knows **nothing** about the old one. Just pass it in:

```
public Client(Form1 form)
{
   //Do whatever with it
}

//Form class
Client c = new Client(this);
```

Disclaimer: There are usually far better ways to do this, but you'll learn those as you get more familiar with design patterns/architecture.

Comment: To access to Form1 controls within Client class, you either need to create internal properties in Form1 or change the "Modifiers" property of the controls you want to process to "internal".

Comment: @Graffito While true, its clear he already has the access to the members he needs, he just shouldn't have been creating a new form in `Client`